# Inter-pipeline dependency and multi-stage pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Use case:
I have [a pipeline](https://github.com/eduherminio/AoCHelper/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) with two stages:

- One to be triggered by every PR/commit to master (build + tests).
- One to be triggered only when an input variable is provided, for publishing a new package version. This one depends on the first one.

The last step of the second stage, after the package gets published, is to automatically commit a change to the repository.

However, I'm not being able to override GitHub branch protection rules from Azure DevOps, so I cannot make that commit due to the pipeline not being 'green' yet.

I've thought of separating both stages in two pipelines, and make my 'publish' pipeline depend on the 'build + tests' one (as if it was one of the old 'Release pipelines', but keeping everything in my `.yml` files).

---

My questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong and should I be able to override GitHub branch protection rules from Azure DevOps?
- Is it possible to split my multistage pipeline in two, and make one depend on the other?
- Can you think of any other pattern to achieve my purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong and should I be able to override GitHub branch protection rules from Azure DevOps?

If you want to push changes to that github repo, then you have to match the GitHub branch protection rules. In Azure DevOps Git, we can bypass the branch policies. The problem is that we cannot override GitHub branch protection rules from Azure DevOps.

> Is it possible to split my multistage pipeline in two, and make one depend on the other?

Yes, we can split multistage pipeline in two, but to push the changes we still need to meet the GitHub branch protection rules. So, the key point is how to bypass or meet the rules.

> Can you think of any other pattern to achieve my purpose?

No other better ways, whatever in one multistage pipeline or split two, we have to meet the rules. If we cannot meet the rules, then we have to bypass the rules or disable the GitHub branch protection rules.

Comment: My idea was splitting it, making one depend on the other and linking the GitHub branch policy to the first one; but now I'm noticing how pushing from the last one probably won't fulfill policy requirements...